# What is the significance of while(true) condition?

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

I was going through a piece of code today in javascript and suddenly came across a situation where there was this piece of snippet.

```
add: function (value) {
    var current = null;
    if (this._root === null) {
        this._root = node;
    } else {
        current = this._root;

        while (true) {
            // Some code goes here.
        }
    }
}
```

The condition `while(true)` will always be true right. Its not getting into my head on why is while condition placed here.

Comment: Sometimes the logic needed for breaking the loop is complex enough that it's more convenient to put it in the body of the loop with a `break` statement. Extra care is needed to ensure that there's always some condition that will break the loop. The same holds true if the condition is in the head of the loop of course, but when the conditions are complex, it can be easier to miss something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`while(true)`

will execute forever, there has to be some logic *inside* of the infinite while loop to terminate.

As to *why?*, this is a really common way to display an infinite loop followed closely by

```
for(;;){}
```

Comment: Cool, interesting when will this be false, until the entire logic of if/else returns something.... http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/06/09/computer-science-in-javascript-binary-search-tree-part-1/ [ i was looking at the add function].

Comment: It will never actually be *false*, the `break` statements in the code you linked will leave the loop once you have found the position to insert your new node.

Answer (score 1):

The while statement will execute the code in the loop endlessly, unless you have logic inside that either calls `break`, or `return` to terminate the loop.

**Example**

```
if (value == "done")
   break;
```

or

```
if (value == "done")
    return;
```

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, this is a very bad practice. 
You should always bind condition to a boolean variable in a conditional loop. This is simply because of the fact that if you use variables, its value can be changed later on. From what I can see, this looks like an infinite loop.
 However, if you look closer to the code inside that loop, you might find some condition, an if statement perhaps using a break statement to break out of that infinite loop.